# Passing a struct Type in Golang?

Tags: json, go, reflection, unmarshalling

Please forgive my question, I'm new to Golang and possibly have the wrong approach.

I'm currently implementing a Terraform provider for an internal service.

As probably expected, that requires unmarshalling JSON data in to pre-defined Struct Types, e.g:

```golang
type SomeTypeIveDefined struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name String `json:"name"`
}
```

I've got myself in to a situation where I have a lot of duplicate code that looks like this

```golang
    res := r.(*http.Response)
    var tempThing SomeTypeIveDefined
    dec := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    err := dec.Decode(&tempThing)
```

In an effort to reduce duplication, I decided what I wanted to do was create a function which does the JSON unmarshalling, but takes in the Struct Type as a parameter.

I've trawled through several StackOverflow articles and Google Groups trying to make sense of some of the answers around using the [reflect package](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect), but I've not had much success in using it.

My latest attempt was using `reflect.StructOf` and passing in a set of `StructField`s, but that still seems to require using `myReflectedStruct.Field(0)` rather than `myReflectedStruct.ID`.

I *suspect* there may be no way until something like Generics are widely available in Golang.

I considered perhaps an interface for the structs which requires implementing an unmarshal method, then I could pass the interface to the function and call the unmarshal method. But then I'm still implementing unmarshal on all the structs anyway.

I'm just wondering what suggestions there may be for achieving what I'm after, please?

Comment: How would the function that you're describing create less duplication? I can't think of a version that is smaller than the one-liner  `json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&tempThing)`. Could you maybe provide an example function signature for the hypothetical function you're looking for?

Comment: @maxm: So the question was somewhat simplified to make it hopefully easier to understand, and answer. But the unmarshal takes place in a larger method (I didn't mention) that reduces other duplication as well. 

But insofar as this more contrived example goes, you're right. It has marginal benefits at face value.

Comment: "In an effort to reduce duplication," bad idea.  "I decided what I wanted to do was create a function which does the JSON unmarshalling, but takes in the Struct Type as a parameter." You cannot do that.

Comment: @Volker I'd be curious your reasoning behind reducing duplication being a bad idea. 

In my professional experience it's common practice to not repeat code if there's clear repetition. Early abstraction is, of course, a bad thing. In my case I have countless examples of the exact same code.

Would you mind elaborating on what specifically is a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a helper function with the repeated code.  Pass the destination value as a pointer.

```
func decode(r *http.Repsonse, v interface{}) error {
     return json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(v)
}
```

Call the helper function with a pointer to your thing:

```
var tempThing SomeTypeIveDefined
err := deocde(r, &tempThing)
```

Comment: I face palmed extremely hard when I read this. I think I got so caught up on not being able to use the field names in the `decode` function that I didn't realise I don't actually need to.

This'll do what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with interfaces:

```
func decodeResponse(r *http.Response, dest interface{}) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    return dec.Decode(dest)
}

func handler(...) {
    res := r.(*http.Response)
    var tempThing SomeTypeIveDefined
    if err:=decodeResponse(res,&tempThing); err!=nil {
      // handle err
    }
   ...
}
```

You don't need to implement an unmarshal for the structs, because the stdlib decoder will use reflection to set the struct fields.

Comment: Same with the other answer, I facepalmed when I read this. It's exactly what I need. I really didn't even need to care about the fields being used in the decoder function. Thanks very much for pointing out my dumb.